# Cleaning a poor quality CSV file, to pull into SPLUNK

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a supposed CSV file (generated by an old internal system) which:-

1. Is displayed in one single column (A1) in EXCEL, or as a line of data in NOTEPAD.
2. Contains no comma's
3. Has variable numbers of whitespaces between each field of data.

So an Example of this to help get the picture in your mind.

UserName       UserEmail             EnquiryCreated   EnquirySubmitted

---

A.nother       anne.nother@mail.com  01/09/201512:00  01/09/201512:01

So wanting to automate the parsing of this large file of data, into a readable CSV format, i was thinking of using POWERSHELL. Essentially I need to replace anywhere there is one or great numbers of horizontal white spaces with a single comma and output as CSV. I'm trying to find the most efficient / elegant method, I'm open to suggestions on this one.

So the ideal format is:-

A.nother,anne.nother@mail.com,01/09/201512:00,01/09/201512:01,

The CSV file is monitored by SPLUNK so will be pulled through automatically.

EDIT - Sam just for clarity, I've done a screen grab because the format gets changed by "Stack overflow".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a77o.jpg)

Comment: Thanks Sam, that should work, I think I over-complicated talking about White space XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing the replacing.  First, create the output file and add the headers.  Then, replace spaces (1 or more) with a comma and add them to the file.

```
Add-Content "C:\temp\output.csv" -Value "UserName,UserEmail,EnquiryCreated,EnquirySubmitted"
Get-Content "C:\temp\input.csv" | % { Add-Content $outputCsv -Value $($_ -replace "\s+", ",") }
```

It's unclear to me if you need your PowerShell script to also detect "one or great numbers of horizontal white spaces" in a file.